# Electron does not get valid version data through the app.getVersion() command

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I cannot understand why my app cannot gets correct version data.

I already add version line in my package.json and I use vue-electron so I write my code in this update component.

```
<template>
  <Window title='Program Updater'>
    <div class='wrap' id='currentAppVersion'>
      Current App Version : {{currentAppVersion}}
    </div>
    <div class='wrap' id='checkNewVersion'>
      Latest App Version : {{latestAppVersion}}
    </div>
    <button class='login' @click="$emit(updateCheck ? 'exist' : 'latest')">{{updateCheck ? 'Update' : 'latest version!'}}</button>
  </Window>
</template>
```

And in  area I add this codes to get version data from package.json. But it shows 'electron package' version and I don't know why it related with.

[image]
**[part of my index.vue]**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app

  data () {
    return {
      currentAppVersion: app && app.getVersion(),
      latestAppVersion: 'Not yet Developed'
    }
  }
```

At first I thought the error is from electron version is so low. But I read 3.1.X document there is app.getVersion() method and I don't know how to fix it.

Some person said that I can use 'process.env.npm_package_version' command and actually, it works. But in production mode it return no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

With this code, I solve the problem. but in dev mode it doesn't working but in production mode, it works well

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app

  data () {
    return {
      currentAppVersion: app && app.getVersion(),
      latestAppVersion: 'Not yet Developed'
    }
  }
```